# Best way to provide a "tooltip tour"

Tags: javascript, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

What is the best way to provide a quick tour of a webapp using contextual tooltips?

Use case:

- user navigates to the webapp
- some form of popup asking if the user wants a guided tour of the interface
- user can click next on each tooltip to be shown the next one
- user can cancel the tour at any time by clicking some kind of exit X or button

Is there an easy library out there that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have written a short [review][1] about on-page guidance and webapp tours which recently was published at the dailyjs.com. In it you can find several DIY solutions for implementing this functionality.

< shame-less-yet-relevant-plug >
You are also most welcome to check out our [on-page guidance as a service][2] at iridize.com. I hope it is the best way to provide this to your users, and I am pretty sure it would be the easiest.
< /shame-less-yet-relevant-plug >


  [1]: http://dailyjs.com/2012/11/02/on-screen-guidance-intro
  [2]: https://iridize.com

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with Jeff Pickhardt's [Guider-JS](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS) javascript tooltip walk-through library. It's very easy to use (although it has several very advanced features as well), and does exactly what you described.

You can check out [this excellent example](http://jeffpickhardt.com/guiders/) of a tooltip walk-through made with Guider-JS.

If you want to see a working example on a production site, it is used extensively on [optimizely.com](http://www.optimizely.com/)  to provide help and walk-through guides for the user interface.

**UPDATE:** ZURB Foundation is now maintaining the excellent ["Joyride" tooltip tour](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) javascript library.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Please remember to mark this as "Accepted" if it answers your question.

Comment: Joyride is an excellent choice - just cut my dev time in half!

Answer (score 1):

You could also write the tour part yourself using a linked list with an iterator that always calls a callback to set up the tooltip and one to close it. You can then use any tooltip script you want. Here's a quick proof of concept that should show you what I mean:

```
var toolTipList = {
    tooltips: [],
    currentTooltip: {},
    addTooltip: function(tooltip){
        var currentTail = this.tooltips.length > 0 ? this.tooltips[this.tooltips.length - 1] : {};
        var newTail = {
            tooltip: tooltip,
            prev: currentTail
        };
        currentTail.next = newTail;
        this.tooltips.push(newTail);
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.currentTooltip = this.tooltips[0];
        this.currentTooltip.tooltip.callback();
    },

    next: function(){
        if(this.currentTooltip.next){
            this.currentTooltip.tooltip.close();
            this.currentTooltip = this.currentTooltip.next;
            this.currentTooltip.tooltip.callback();        
        }   
    }           
};


for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    toolTipList.addTooltip({
        callback: function(){ 
            // called every time next is called
            // open your tooltip here and 
            // attach the event that calls 
            // toolTipList.next when the next button is clicked
            console.log('called'); 
        },
        close: function(){ 
            // called when next is called again
            // and this tooltip needs to be closed
            console.log('close'); 
        }
    });
}

toolTipList.initialize();

setInterval(function(){toolTipList.next();}, 500);
```

[​JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hAhDF/1/)