# Is there a Javascript Help Framework?

Tags: javascript, intro.js

Is there a Javascript framework that help my end-users to easily use a website?

A framework to become possible from a config file that I specify which buttons, div's ...etc need some information about how to easily use a site.

Comment: You mean a framework for creating tutorials on the live site?

Comment: I don't like to use the 'tutorial' word, because I want something more dynamic. I prefer Live Guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to provide a "tooltip tour"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352917/best-way-to-provide-a-tooltip-tour)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Intro.js** Is a good one, It's like a website *tour* framework, but has the same functionality as what you have described.

> Better introductions for websites and features with a *step-by-step* guide for your projects.
>
> - **Website: http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/**
> - **GitHub: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js**